# How to animate an image transition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am try to make a transitions animation for a slide images.

I have an array with more 5 itens, but need to show 5 items per time. Functionally it's works, but i'am fail in my trys to animate the transisitons between.

To manage the display I'm using an array (slider) that serves to always display only the 5 items. The imgs array can contain dozens of items.

below what I've done so far

```
const [slider, setSlider] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(imgs.length / 2);

const mod = (position: number, totalItems: number) => 
    {
        return ((position % totalItems) + totalItems) % totalItems;
    }

useEffect(() => {
    function ArrangeArray() {
        const slid: string[] = [];
        const totalItems = imgs.length;
        slid.push(imgs[mod(index-2, totalItems)]);
        slid.push(imgs[mod(index-1, totalItems)]);
        slid.push(imgs[mod(index, totalItems)]);
        slid.push(imgs[mod(index+1, totalItems)]);
        slid.push(imgs[mod(index+2, totalItems)]);
        setSlider(slid);
    }
    ArrangeArray();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);

const prevProperty = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1);
    slider.push(imgs[mod(index+2, imgs.length)]);
    slider.shift();
}

const nextProperty = () => {
    setIndex(index - 1);
    slider.unshift(imgs[mod(index-2, imgs.length)]);
    slider.pop();
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="slider-container">
            {slider.map((img, index) => (
                <div key={index} className={`slide${index} img-effect`}>
                    <div>
                        <img src={img} />
                    </div>
                </div>

            ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => prevProperty()}>
            Prev
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => nextProperty()}>
            Next
        </button>
    </>
);
```

Comment: can you share your code on https://codesandbox.io/ includes the css files please

Comment: codesandbox.io/s/goofy-proskuriakova-4nsco. Sorry for the delay to answer. @abdelhedihlel